# Prevent direct access to html pages

Tags: php, html

I have created a simple login page to access mail sending form. Login page works and redirects to sender.html. What I am trying to get is not to let others access sender.html or send.php without logging in. I have already tried putting

```html
<?php
$referrer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'];
if ($referrer != "http://www.example.com/login.html") {
header('Location: http://www.example.com/login.html');
} ;
?>
```

into the beginning of the sender.html but it doesn't work. I also tried adding redirect rules to .htaccess but it would not allow access the page after login.
I'm a beginner but already spent a while to sort this out, would appreciate your help guys.

Answer (score 0):

Change the filename from `sender.html` to `sender.php`. When a file has html extension it won't process php.

Also you could modify the `.htaccess` file to tell the server to process .html files as .php files, but I think it is easier to change the file extension.

Comment: it tried changing `sender.html` to `sender.php` it would loop on login page it takes the creds bit will not access the page.

Comment: Probably the referer is not the one you are expecting. You should listen to @Foon and change the way you are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

First off, checking the referer variable is not a good way to do this; attackers can forge that header.  The easy way would be to use basic authentication to protect your two pages of interest.

Example .htaccess:

```
AuthType Basic
AuthName "Restricted Files"
AuthUserFile /usr/local/apache/passwd/htpasswd
Require valid-user
```

(See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/howto/auth.html for more details as well as how to create the htpasswd file containing your users)

Comment: I would prefer using htpasswd but for this project I must use mysql database to store users.